# Strings are not type checked in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Could somebody explain why the following code compiles in typescript, and ideally how to prevent it from doing so?

```
class Foo {}

function bar(f : Foo) {
  console.log(f)
}

bar("lol wat?")
```

EDIT:
This is just a quick edit to explain why I ran into this problem, to hopefully save some future people some time.
I defined a type

```
type Message = MySubMessageType | SomeImportedConfigMessageType
```

`SomeImportedConfigMessageType` was allowed to be an empty object, and thus any method I defined taking one of my messages would take anything.

Comment: they are.. it's just that your Foo class is really an empty object and can be duck typed by anything. :)

Comment: if you'll add a property or method to it you'll get errors too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is [structurally typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system).

You declare the method `Bar` to take an argument of type `Foo`.

Your type `Foo` does not contain any constraints other than that it's an object.

Strings are also objects, thus they are compatible with your type `Foo`.

There is currently no non-hacky way to get nominal typing in TypeScript, but if you are interested you might want to check out this [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202).

Comment: Hm, string <: empty record... Yay JS hangovers.